# How to connect DbVisualizer to OAC ADW

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dbvisualizer, oracle-analytics

**OAC ADW** = Oracle Analytics Cloud Autonomous Data Warehouse. Our OAC ADW admin provided us **.zip wallet files** for connection, however this is not natively supported by **DbVisualizer**. How can I make the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the notes I developed after getting help from multiple sources and jumping through all the hoops:

```
1. Install [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/)
    a. Need admin access on the machine
    b. This guide uses DbVisualizer Pro 12.0.2 (Build #3211) with Java version 1.8.0_275 included

2. Add Oracle drivers
    a. Visit [Oracle download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-ucp-122-downloads.html) to get three Java packages (Oracle account required): oraclepki.jar, osdt_cert.jar, and osdt_core.jar
    b. Save to DbVisualizer Oracle driver path (e.g. C:\Program Files\DbVisualizer\jdbc\oracle)

3. Configure [Oracle connection files](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Sqlnet.ora)
    a. Get .zip wallet files from OAC ADW admin
    b. Unzip and save to a safe path (e.g. C:\ADW): cwallet.sso, ewallet.p12, keystore.jks, ojdbc.properties, sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora, truststore.jks
    c. Edit "DIRECTORY" part in sqlnet.ora (Oracle database configuration file) to match the wallet file directory:
        WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="C:\ADW")))
        SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=yes
    d. Edit system environment variable to set TNS_ADMIN = "C:\ADW" to tell DbVisualizer where to find tnsnames.ora file (configuration file that defines Oracle database address)
    e. Note: if you machine already has TNS_ADMIN set, check if that path already contains a tnsnames.ora ("remote tnsnames.ora file"). If so
        i. If your OAC ADW admin allows you to edit that file, copy content of the tnsnames.ora file in your wallet file path ("local tnsnames.ora file") and append to the end of that remote file. Don't change your machine's TNS_ADMIN
        ii. If you can't edit that remote file, copy its content and append to the local file. Then proceed to set TNS_ADMIN = "C:\ADW"
    f. Repeat the process for every OAC ADW environment (prod, test, etc)

4. Configure DbVisualizer
    a. Launch DbVisualizer. If the JDBC Driver Finder opens automatically, also close it (you already manually saved the Oracle drivers you need for now)
    b. Create a new connection to OAC ADW using the Connection Wizard
        i. Select Database Driver = "Oracle Thin", Service = "TNS"
        ii. You should be able to pick "TNS Alias" from a dropdown list that contains the OAC ADW you're looking for. If not, check Step 3. Note: if you have DbVisualizer open before Step 3, you must re-launch it to have the new TNS_ADMIN in effect. Also after setting TNS_ADMIN you must click "OK" to apply the change
        iii. Enter Database Userid and Password your OAC ADW admin provided, "Finish"
        iv. Note: before you try the connection, you must go to "Properties" > "Driver Properties", scroll to parameter "oracle.net.wallet_location", enter "C:\ADW", and click "Apply"
        v. If using the filepath alone does not work, use the following string instead: 
            (SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY="C:\ADW")))

5. Now you should be all set. If not, check all steps and a few other things:
    a. You have updated to the newest version of DbVisualizer
    b. If mixed Oracle drivers are installed, uninstall/remove other ones
    c. Check if environment variable ORACLE_HOME is defined. This is because tnsnames.ora file could be found in two places: path defined by TNS_ADMIN, as well as %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin
```